# как сделать так, чтобы в сортировку не входили слова меньше чем из 3-х букв

Tags: python

```
vvid = bool(int(input("1 якщо сортувати , 2 якщо рахувати: ")))
text=str(input("Enter text: "))
if (vvid  == 1):
    data = sorted(list(set(text.split())))
    print(data); 

elif (vvid == 2):
    words = sorted(list(set(text.split())))
    data = dict()  
    for letter in text:
         data[letter] = data.get(letter, 0) + 1
print(data)
```

Comment: а как вы это себе представляете? их позиция должна быть неизменной до и после сортировки?

Comment: слова должны быть отсортированными по алфаывиту, но слова меньше трёх букв не должны быть в финальном списке

Answer (score 0):

например так:

слова из менее чем 3х букв останутся неотсортированными, т.е. на своих первоначальных местах:

```
words = list(set(text.split()))

# сформировать список слов, удовлетворяющий критериям
tmp = sorted([word for word in words if len(word) >= 3])

# выполнить замену слов, удовлетворяющих критериям
i_tmp = 0
for i in range(len(words)):
    if len(words[i]) >= 3:
        words[i] = tmp[i_tmp]
        i_tmp += 1
```

> слова должны быть отсортированными по алфаывиту, но слова меньше трёх
> букв не должны быть в финальном списке

ну тогда надо сделать всего лишь так:

```
words = sorted([word for word in list(set(text.split())) if len(word) >= 3])
```

Comment: спасибо, но куда его надо всавить в код, и ещё, как исправить то, когда я ввожу слова у меня они и сортируються и считаються одновременно, как именно разделить ети процесы?

Comment: не понял, почему считаются и сортируются одновременно? у вас же в разных местах это делается или вы что-то другое имеете в виду?

Comment: я тоже не понимаю,

Comment: 1 якщо сортувати , 2 якщо рахувати: 1
Enter text: ррор ппа лдлп па
['лдлп', 'па', 'ппа', 'ррор']
{'р': 3, 'о': 1, ' ': 3, 'п': 4, 'а': 2, 'л': 2, 'д': 1}

Comment: вы бы на русский перевели :) т.е. вам надо чтобы когда пользователь наберет 1 - ему отсортировало, а 2 - подсчитало? если так - то где считаете посмотрите свой пример и отступы - у вас блок подсчета вне условия находится

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "d:\Python starter\laba 2.py", line 11, in <module>
        data[letter] = data.get(letter, 0) + 1
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: вот что мне выбило

Comment: может я не так понял, я просто добавил таб перед         data = dict()

Comment: приведите весь код - можно даже в своем вопросе сделать правку с P.S., а то так сложно воспринимать по частям

Comment: вот, сделал так как у меня в интерпретаторе

Comment: перед `for` отступа нет или это тут так отображается?

Comment: нет, его нету, а надо?

Comment: я поставил отступ,  data[letter] = data.get(letter, 0) + 1 выдала ошибку, я отступил и перед ним, но  у меня просто слова одинаковые в две строчки в[] пишуться, и не убиают нужные слова

Comment: у меня никаких ошибок не выдается, попробовал ваш текст, кстати у вас `vvid = bool(...)`, а вы сравниваете его с `1` и с `2`, но `bool` - это про другое, замените на `int`, затем при 2 вы зачем-то анализируете буквы `for letter in text:`, хотя, как я понял вам надо анализировать слова `for letter in words:`